# Ireports with jsp

Tags: jsp, ireport

I am new to Jasper reports(iReports).
Is there any tutorial to generate reports using iReport from JSP?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

JSF library exists for Jasper Reports. Look at [here](http://jasperreportjsf.sourceforge.net/web/index.html)